# Join 3 Tables DB

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have 3 tables: `CUSTOMERS`, `REGISTRATION` and `TUITION` table.

The `Registration` table has foreign key:

```
ID_CLIENTES (FK)
ID_AULAS (FK)
```

And primary key:

```
ID_INSCRICAO
```

The objective is to create a select, but which has all the tables according to the inscriptions ie (table.attribute):

```
INSCRICAO.ID_INSCRICAO | INSCRICAO.DATA | CLIENTES.CNOME | AULAS.ANOME | AULAS.DATA | AULAS.VAGAS |
```

Have tried using the model:

```
SELECT INSCRICAO.ID_INSCRICAO, 
  INSCRICAO.DATA, 
  CLIENTES.CNOME, 
  AULAS.ANOME,
  AULAS.DATA,
  AULAS.VAGAS
FROM table1 INSCRICAO
left outer join table2 CLIENTES 
   on INSCRICAO.ID_INSCRICAO=CLIENTES.ID_CLIENTES
left outer join table3 AULAS 
   on AULAS.ID_AULA = INSCRICAO.ID_INSCRICAO;
```

That gives me error or multiplies the rows of tables, and the goal was to have the same number of records that the table entries

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data ? And expected result ?

Comment: Please provide some sample using SQLfiddle, it ill help us to help you (also do you knows there are a portuguese version of SO now?)

Comment: Of the following error: Error starting at line : 1 in command -
SELECT INSCRICAO.ID_INSCRICAO, INSCRICAO.DATA, CLIENTES.CNOME, AULAS.ANOME,AULAS.DATA,AULAS.VAGAS
FROM table1 INSCRICAO
left outer join 
  table2 CLIENTES on INSCRICAO.ID_INSCRICAO=CLIENTES.ID_CLIENTES
left outer join
  table3 AULAS on AULAS.ID_AULA = INSCRICAO.ID_INSCRICAO
Error at Command Line : 6 Column : 3
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action: